# Can I remove default scopes added by Google Workspace Marketplace SDK configuration?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to publish a Google Sheets Add-on. I am working on the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK configuration. The configuration automatically includes the following 2 scopes as defaults:

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

The Add-on has no reason to access the user's email or profile. Why are these added? Can I delete them? The only scopes that the script code should need are:

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly
```

When I go to create the OAuth Consent Screen. I am told that I need to create "A Youtube video showing how you plan to use the Google user data that you get from scopes". Am I being asked to do this because of these default scopes that are included?

EDIT: I deleted these 2 scopes and did a SAVE. It confirmed that the edits were saved. But when I refreshed the page, the scopes were back!

Comment: Try deleting one of the  required scopes(`container.ui` or `spreadsheets`)  then delete them (`email`) and see if it comes back.

Comment: @TheMaster I just tried that, in various combinations. The email & profile scopes always come back.

Comment: You may contact Google support directly or create a issue in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for issuetracker link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the Trust and Safety team is asking you for the video is because this:

1-Most of the apps that will be public, require certain steps. So the video is one of those.

2-Now, the main reason for the video, is because the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui` is part of the restricted scopes. And according to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) it needs to go through the verification.

So basically the reason for the video is because you have a restricted scope because this scope allows you to display and run third-party web content in prompts and sidebars inside Google applications. Therefore, it is important for the verification process.

Now in regards to your concern of the default scopes, I was able to remove them and create OAuth consent screen without them.

Comment: Thanks for that info. But when you say you were able to remove them, do you mean from the panel that opens when you click the "ADD OR REMOVE SCOPES" in the OAuth consent screen or on the Marketplace SDK config screen? When I open the panel on the consent screen, I only see the 2 scopes container.ui and spreadsheets.currentonly. It is on the Marketplace config screen that I have the 4 scopes and can not remove the email and profile ones.

Comment: Yes, I have done it through the 2 forms you mentioned. And I was able to save it. You can check on this Screenshot I just took https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uQ7kn1DE6mGVhj8C0W6TDvkbUBaK95xh/view?usp=sharing  you will be able to delete those unnecessary scopes when hovering your mouse over those scopes. A trash bin gets triggered for you to remove.

Comment: I tried that 3 times now on the Marketplace config screen (same as in your screenshot). I hover and click on the trash bin. Each of the 2 scopes gets deleted. I then click on the SAVE on the bottom of the screen. A small popup says "Saved". But then when I refresh the page in the browser, the 2 scopes that I deleted are back! I tried closing the browser tab and waiting an hour, but when I return to that screen, the deleted scopes are there.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for bringing that up. You are right! They always come back. 

Yet I investigated and this is expected because these scopes are necessary for any app verification since OAuth requires these [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#oauth2) by default they are mandatory.

So despite those scopes, the ones you really wanted initially have a restricted scope. So you would have needed to provide the YouTube video anyways.

Comment: That seems to imply that any public (as opposed to private) add-on, even if unlisted (which mine is) will always have restricted scopes. Is that true?

Comment: Any add-on, web app, etc. requires to go through the verification whenever it is going to be public in most of the cases. So the video will always be required. Private apps/add-ons don't need to go through verification because it is for domain internal use. These scopes are needed because that's how the add-on works for Google services. What you only need to do is to prove the use of your add-on through the scopes you are using. And explain that the default scopes are only for registration purposes and basic data for analysis only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247148/discussion-between-john-pankowicz-and-cizranger).